# Jquery ui autocomplete - suggest with external json

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using jquery ui autocomplete.

My problem is when I use a call to a external json, the suggest function stops working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.comu').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/edusl/test/master/municipios1.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: response
      });
    },
    minLength: 0,
    autoFocus: true,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(".comu").val(ui.item.label);
    },
  });
});
```

Example of my code: [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oBMyrO)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The first thing I notice is you do not pass any `data` to your `url`, so what are you expected to get back?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you could have found someone that answered this already. But here is a solution for you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.comu').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/edusl/test/master/municipios1.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(jData) {
          var results = [];
          $.each(jData, function(ind, val) {
            if (val.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.term) === 0) {
              results.push(val);
            }
          });
          response(results);
        }
      });
    },
    minLength: 0,
    autoFocus: true,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(".comu").val(ui.item.label);
    },
  });
});
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/mL3h8pm0/

The AJAX request will just return all the results, and that is what you are passing to your `response`. So if you do not filter that down before you pass it to `response` you will always end up with a complete list.

This filters the list using `indexOf()` but you can use any method you'd like.

Here is another solution that will cut down on your HTTP overhead:

```
var m = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/edusl/test/master/municipios1.json", function(result) {
    $.each(result, function(ind, val) {
      m.push(val);
    });
  });

  $('.comu').autocomplete({
    source: m,
    minLength: 0,
    autoFocus: true,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(".comu").val(ui.item.label);
    },
  });
});
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/mL3h8pm0/2/

This gets all the data once and populates an array. Autocomplete can then use this like normal.